# Segmentation fault opening a file in ADA

Tags: linux, file-io, segmentation-fault, ada

I have to port some legacy software written in ADA from Windows to Linux. The program compiles fine, but terminates with a segmentation fault when executed.

The segfault occurs when the program tries to open a file (the file exists ;). Strange to say, the program succeeds in opening another file earlier in the execution without an error. Both files are binary files.

Stepping through the program with gdb, I could track down the last line executed to

```
DIO.Open (FP (File), To_FCB (Mode), Name, Form);
```

which is defined in a-direio.adb, line 167.

How can I further investigate the cause of the fault? The values of the parameters to *DIO.Open* look OK (they are the same as for the previous successful call to *DIO.Open*, except for the file name). Any hints are appreciated.

---

### Edit

Here is the code that eventually calls *DIO.Open*:

```
procedure Open
 (The_File      : in out File_Type;
  The_Mode      : in     A_DB_Mode := DBS_Database_Types.InOut_DB;
  The_Name      : in     String;
  The_Form      : in     String    := "") is
begin

  Ada_File_IO.Open
    (File => The_File,
     Mode => DB_Mode_To_File_Mode(The_Mode),
     Name => The_Name,
     Form => The_Form);

exception
  when Ada_File_IO.Status_Error => raise Status_Error;
  when Ada_File_IO.Name_Error   => raise Name_Error;
  when Ada_File_IO.Use_Error    => raise Use_Error;

end Open;
```

where *ADA_File_IO* is declared as

```
package Ada_File_IO is 
  new Ada.Direct_IO(Element_Type => GNL_Universal_Representation.An_Item);
```

GNL_Universal_Representation.An_Item resolves to

```
subtype An_Item is GNL_Basic_Types.A_Byte;
type A_Byte is mod 2**Byte_Size;
```

and *DB_Mode_To_File_Mode(The_Mode)* resolves to *Ada_File_IO.In_File*.

---

### Edit (2)

This is the gdb output with some filenames (as suggested by Brian)

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb563db40 (LWP 9887)]
0x081053af in system.file_io.open ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x081053af in system.file_io.open ()
#1  0x080fd447 in system.direct_io.open ()
#2  0x08066182 in dbs_file.ada_file_io.open (file=0x0, mode=in_file, name=..., 
    form=...)
    at /media/chmiwah/ADA/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/adainclude/a-direio.adb:167
#3  0x080665cc in dbs_file.open (the_file=0x0, the_mode=in_db, the_name=..., 
    the_form=...)
    at /media/chmiwah/GISMO/bbp-benchmark/code/rebsys/src/dbs/ntv/bdy/dbs_file.adb:108
#4  0x080631b0 in dbs_database.open (the_database=0xb5500468, the_mode=in_db, 
    the_name=..., the_form=..., using_the_definition=0xb5646008)
    at /media/chmiwah/GISMO/bbp-benchmark/code/rebsys/src/dbs/gnc/bdy/dbs_database.adb:363
```

Comment: I would suggest compiling & linking with debug info and all warnings (e.g. `-Wall -g`) then use the `gdb` debugger. Perhaps using `strace` might help also.

Comment: Please post the code you used to call `Your_Direct_IO.Open` (`Your_Direct_IO` would be your generic instantiation).  Also, the `Direct_IO` instantiation itself and any information about types used in it would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I have posted more information about the code. The compiler/linker options for debugging were already set before. I will now investigate if strace can provide some useful information.

Comment: It might be worth seeing the filenames, given the differences between the underlying OS functions.

Comment: Based on the info I've seen so far, my #1 concern would be, where does the file name come from.  Since the program is seg-faulting, it seems possible that somewhere, the program has created a file name with a totally ridiculous length, due to mishandling a C string returned by the OS.  It is also conceivable that this string could be passed around between several routines and not cause any problem until a subprogram is called that actually looks at the string's contents, such as `DIO.Open`.

Comment: Thanks, ajb, for your response. I set a breakpoint just before `DIO.Open` and the file name passed to this function looks OK. The file exists and has rwx rights for the current user.

Comment: Sorry for late response - Looking at the Dialogue so far I suspect looking closely at the File names & paths closely. This looks like an OS difference. Are you re-using the same File pointer or name? or is the 2nd file located at somewhere Linux cannot resolve like a different drive? (z:\here\file.txt)

Comment: @MichaelWahler, I am pretty sure Brian meant the file names passed to `Open`.  Are you allowed to instrument the source text?  Could you try to insert an `Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("""" & The_Name & """");` just before the call to `Open`?

Comment: **I'd like to** **sincerely thank everybody who took the time to think about my problem and reply to it. It is really amazing that there are so many people out there who care to help others!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using a multi-threaded program. When using gdb, note that 'bt' will not be terribly useful, as it only shows one thread (I can't rememeber if this is the main thread or the current thread).

Instead, using the following:

```
thread apply all bt
```

or

```
thread apply all bt full
```

Also, using `strace -f -e trace=file your_program args` will be useful to determine if the fault comes before or after the system call to open.

It would be quite useful to know what version of the compiler you are using, and what options were used to build it (esp. if any warnings were disabled).

Are the filename encoding anything more or less than US-ASCII?

Comment: Using strace I found out that the the OS's open function is never even reached, so the program must have crashed before that. After a long search I found out that the stack size of the ADA task that crashed was configured (using a pragma) to be too small. After increasing it, the seg fault did not occur anymore.